# Can I add some public meta data to an encrypted Access 2010 database?

Tags: ms-access

My application stores its data in an Access 2010 database (accdb) file.  It's password protected, which means it's encrypted w/ AES-128.

I'd like to add some meta data to the file that's publically available.  This way older verisons of my application can investigate the file to see if it's even worth trying to open.  Otherwise, they'll just get the dreaded "Unrecognized Database Format" error, which is usually associated with file corruptions.

In Windows, you can right-click on a file, click "Properties" and see attributes under the Details tab.  I'd love it if I add attributes like the version of my application that last touched the file, and maybe other details.  I'd like to avoid having a different file extension for each version of my app!

Is it possible to add some public meta data to an encrypted Access 2010 database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tough nut to crack!  An application must read information about the ACCDB, but that information can't be stored in the ACCDB because you want the read without opening the ACCDB.  And you can't use the suggested file system methods because this must work under Wine on Mac (I assume from another of your questions).

The only solution I can see is to create a companion file (with same base name but different extension) to hold the metadata.  So if your application wants to know about SomeDb.accdb, it would look for a file named SomeDb.metadata and read that instead.

I suggested a kludge for your earlier question ... unfortunately this is another.  :-)  However, it's a simple kludge and it *should* work ... even on Mac.

Comment: Thanks.  This is the same conclusion I came to.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You can add custom database properties : http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;q178745</s>

You can change the file extension of an encrypted Access database and change the properties for that extension. The extension .enc is fairly descriptive and does not seem to be widely used.

[image: Open with]

The file will open normally when clicked and ask for the password. The icon will be recognizably Access and the description, "Encrypted MS Access" in this case, will appear under Type in a directory listing.

[image: Icon]

With NTFS, you can add an alternate data stream (ADS):

```
notepad.exe z:\docs\testde.enc:Extra.txt
```

Reading the stream:

```
more < testde.enc:extra.txt
```

More information:
 http://www.think-techie.com/2010/04/alternate-data-streams.html

http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/altds

Comment: Only problem is, those database properties aren't available until after you provide the password, and the database is decrypted.

Comment: isn't that the point of encryption. The information contained within the database is secured.

Comment: I'd like to add a few hundred bytes of non-encrypted data to describe the rest of the encrypted portion of the file.

Comment: That NTFS alternative data stream might work.  I'll check it out.  Thanks!

Comment: Just looked into NTFS ADS.  Pretty interesting to me.  Would work in an NTFS-only world.  These alternate streams are not preserved when copying the file to a non-NTFS drive.