# Do aspx/cs files contain meta data?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, metadata, meta

Do the aspx, aspx.cs, web.config and accdb contain any meta data that can be read when I publish my site? (E.g. the information that can be required by reading out jpeg files).

If yes, how to view/edit this?

P.s. Except the properties shown in windows explorer of course.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must have something specific in mind that you want to look for?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is in your aspx file, that's all what is there.
If you have added some metadata there (usually in the < head>< /head> tags), then it will be there, otherwise not.

The aspx.cs file is never really sent to the webbrowser, so there is no question of it having metadata or not.

Answer (score 0):

`aspx.cs web.config` files are plain text files with different extensions, they don't contain embedded metadata (data which would describe the content, etc).

As for the `.accdb` files, you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154393/can-i-add-some-public-meta-data-to-an-encrypted-access-2010-database)